# Download remote Database on local and Create a new Database from that mysql dump file

Tags: mysql, database, terminal, relational-database

I want to do simply two things:

1. Download Remote Database on local
2. Install that dump on my local database

Through Terminal

Need a simple and clear solutions

Answer (score 1):

**Steps:**

To Download Database on local

> 1.`mysqldump -u root -p --databases DB_NAME >databasename.sql`

To Install Downloaded Dump on local

> 1. `mysql -u root -p`
> 2. `create database DB_NAME_LOCAL;`
> 3. `use DB_NAME_LOCAL;`
> 4. `source databasename.sql`
> 5. `show tables`